# How can I write a decorator in Django to check two separate conditions and redirect accordingly?

Tags: python, django, authentication, decorator

In my project, once registered, a user must create a `Profile` before accessing the rest of the site. I'd like a decorator `@profile_decorator` to use in place of `@login_decorator`.

If the user is

1. not logged in, redirect to `login URL`
2. logged in, but does not have a `profile`, redirect to `create profile URL`
3. logged in, has `profile`, allowed to proceed to view

This is from `django.contrib.auth.decorators`:

```
from functools import wraps

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse


def user_passes_test(test_func, login_url=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user passes the given test,
    redirecting to the log-in page if necessary. The test should be a callable
    that takes the user object and returns True if the user passes.
    """

    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request.user):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            resolved_login_url = resolve_url(login_url or settings.LOGIN_URL)
            # If the login url is the same scheme and net location then just
            # use the path as the "next" url.
            login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
            current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
            if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
                    (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
                path = request.get_full_path()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(
                path, resolved_login_url, redirect_field_name)
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator


def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
    to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated(),
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

from django.conf.settings import CREATE_PROFILE_REDIRECT_URL

from .models import Profile


def profile_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in and has created
    a profile, redirecting to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        test_func,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator


def test_func(u):
    if u.is_authenticated():
        if Profile.objects.filter(user=u).exists():
            return True
    return False
```

And now I'm just confused, having realised I don't know how make this react differently to `1.` and `2.`.

**EDIT:** The `login_required` decorator has additional functionality that I'd like to preserve - it redirects the user back to the original page they tried to access after a successful login. Sorry, should have said to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are helping yourself by trying to use the `user_passes_test` decorator. You would find this much easier if you created the decorator from scratch yourself.

```
def profile_required(view_func):
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
            path = request.build_absolute_uri()
            from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
            return redirect_to_login(path, LOGIN_URL)
        else:
            try:
                profile = request.user.profile
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                return redirect(CREATE_PROFILE_REDIRECT_URL)
            else:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Comment: I wanted to preserve the `login_required` functionality - after login, it redirects the user back to the page they were taken from, and I don't really understand how to replicate it

Comment: That's just because it uses the `redirect_to_login` function and passes it the current path from `request.path`. Example updated.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
from functools import wraps

def profile_required(view_func):
  def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        return redirect(LOGIN_URL)
    else:
        try:
            profile = Profile.object.get(user=request.user)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('userprofile_url')

    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return response
return wraps(view_func)(_decorator)


@profile_required
def your_func(request):
   # do something
```

Comment: I wanted to preserve the `login_required` functionality - after login, it redirects the user back to the page they were taken from, and I don't really understand how to replicate it